# How to set environment variable in supervisord using output from a file

Tags: linux, environment-variables, supervisord

What is the good way to set environment variable in supervisord using output from a file?
I need like:

```
[program:prog1]
command=prog1 -param1 -param2
environment=PASSWORD=`cat .password`
```

I can use an additional script, but perhaps the better way exists:

```
[program:prog1]
command=start-prog1
```

start-prog1:

```
export PASSWORD=`cat .password`
start-prog1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038511/supervisord-using-a-variable-inside-the-supervisord-conf

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Thank @dekkard, but I haven't found the answer on my question in that post.

Comment: Thank @jww. I'll ask on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.